# How do I get Web API and Swagger to support an "int or const-string" route parameter?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

My Web API has route-paths like this:

```
/api/tenants/{tenantId:int}/documents/{documentId:int}
```

And Web API Controller actions like this;

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Int32 tenantId, Int32 documentId)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

To make the API easier to use I want to allow `{tenantId}` to be replaced with a const string "self" so that clients don't need to remember their Tenant ID.

I currently do that by applying two `Route` attributes and making the `tenantId` parameter nullable:

```
[Route("api/tenants/{tenantId:int}/documents/{documentId:int}")
[Route("api/tenants/self/documents/{documentId:int}")
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Int32? tenantId, Int32 documentId)
{
}
```

But this results in Swagger and NSwag generating client code like below, which is not what I want:

```
public async Task<bservableCollection<Document>> GetListAsync(int? tenantId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var urlBuilder_ = new StringBuilder();
    urlBuilder_.Append(BaseUrl != null ? BaseUrl.TrimEnd('/') : "").Append("/api/tenants/self/documents?");
    if (tenantId != null) 
    {
        urlBuilder_.Append("tenantId=").Append( Uri.EscapeDataString( ConvertToString( tenantId, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))).Append("&");
    }
    urlBuilder_.Length--;
    // ...
```

See how it incorrectly added `tenantId` as a querystring parameter instead of inserting it into the URI path.